# C# Lambda: Manipulate single item in List<T>

Tags: c#, list, lambda

**What I'm doing**

I'm developing some prototype systems (inventory, equipment, ...) for my Unity 2D RPG game. There I'm facing a problem with the `List<Stat> stats` that the player holds.

**What I'm trying to do**

In case the player picks up an item, it gets directly equipped (for now). The item can hold a `List<StatModifier> modifiers` that get added to the `PlayerStats`. Whenever an item gets equipped, the following delegate gets fired, which is part of the `EquipmentSystem` class (Singleton).

```
public delegate void OnEquipmentChanged(EquipableItem newItem, EquipableItem oldItem);
public OnEquipmentChanged onEquipmentChanged;
```

The PlayerStats class subscribes to this delegate the moment it is created.

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    List<StatModifier> empty = new List<StatModifier>();

    // Initialize Stats
    health = new Stat(100, empty, StatType.HP);
    mana = new Stat(200, empty, StatType.MANA);

    // Add stats to list
    stats = new List<Stat>();
    stats.Add(health);
    stats.Add(mana);

    // Subscribe new Function
    EquipmentSystem.instance.onEquipmentChanged += OnEquipmentChanged; 
}
```

The `OnEquipmentChanged()`-method then recalculates the stats of the player by removing the `StatModifier`s from the old item and adding the `StatModifier`s from the new item. Those stats are stored in a `private List<Stat> stats` within the `PlayerStats` class.

**What my problem is**

The `OnEquipmentChanged()`-method gets called correctly but it does not work as intended. The `StatModifier`s of the item should only be added if the `StatType` is the same as the `StatType` of the `Stat`. So HP should only be added to HP, Mana only to Mana and so on. `StatType` is a public enum btw. But the function currently adds all `StatModifier`s to all `Stat`s the player has. Here's the function:

```
void OnEquipmentChanged(EquipableItem newItem, EquipableItem oldItem)
{
    if (oldItem != null) { //remove modifiers }
    if (newItem != null)
    {
        // add modifiers of new item if new item exists
        foreach (StatModifier item_sm in newItem.GetStatModifiers())
        {                
            int index = stats.FindIndex(stat => stat.GetStatType() == item_sm.GetStatType());

            Debug.Log("Found stat " + stats[index].GetStatType());

            stats[index].AddModifier(item_sm);
            Debug.Log("Added " + item_sm.GetModifierValue() + " " + (StatType)item_sm.GetStatType() + " to " + stats[index].GetStatType());
        }
    }
}
```

Setting a breakpoint shows, that after the first iteration the `StatModifier` has already been added to both `Stat`s. Why is that?

**EDIT 1**: Here's the (very simple) code that is used to add a `StatModifier` to any `Stat`. Every `Stat` has it's own private List of `StatModifier`.

```
public void AddModifier(StatModifier modifier)
{
    if (modifier != null)
    {
        modifiers.Add(modifier);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I strongly recommend keeping the player base stats as your underlying state and computing the effective stats as needed, instead of having your state contain the adjusted stats.  If you keep base stats as state, then a bugged item only affects things while it is equipped.  If you keep the adjusted stats, then a bugged item has permanent effects (which probably stack each time you unequip and reequip it).

Comment: Also, please don't use singletons for such purpose. There will be a time you might need another inventory for something else, not to say someone unauthorized might mess with your inventory. In general, mutable global state is bad.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint *before* the first iteration? I see only 1 index access, per iteration so I think it must be something else messing with the modifiers.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Could you please elaborate on that? The final value of a `Stat` is composed of its base value and the sum of all `StatModifiers` that are stored in its private list. The method returning that final value uses a local variable so computation is done only when needed. But in order to do that calculation i need my List of `StatModifier`s to be updated, right?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on this line:

```
stats[index].AddModifier(item_sm);
```

Whatever the implementation of `AddModifier` you have, it's doing the wrong thing.

The whole code is needlessly complicated and brittle though, why a list of same-objects representing different stats that you have to find with `FindIndex`? That's what dictionaries are for. In fact, that's what separate variables are for, and it would make your code so much more efficient.

The other really huge problem is that you can't equip items like this, by first removing the effects of the item you replace then adding the new item. Think about order of operations here, any `flat life` stat removed will be removed before the contribution from your other gear's `life%` stat. The correct way is to keep a list of every modifier, whatever its source, and when needed go over it all, sum up the correct things in the correct order and then use the stat.

Comment: I've posted the code of `AddModifier`. Can't see anything wrong there, but maybe I've been staring at it for too long. Thank you for pointing out the dictionnaries. I've been thinking about using those. The key will be the `StatType` and the value will be a `Stat`. About your last point: I don't recalculate the stats, I simply update the List of `StatModifier` in order to get the final value when needed. Every `Stat` has a `GetFinalValue()` that takes the `baseValue` and adds all `StatModifier`s to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach I don't think lambda is the way to go. This is pseudo code I don't have all your class code so I can't write the code exactly for you, but I would do something like this.

```
foreach (StatModifier item_sm in newItem.GetStatModifiers())
{           
     foreach (Stat stat in stats) {
          if (item_sm.GetStatType() == stat.statType) {
          // remove previous stat from a previous equipped item
          stat.AddModifier(item_sm);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: This is the original way I went. Yet it results in the same. This probably strenghtens Blindys statement, that my `AddModifier` is doing something wrong...